# Firefox doesn't open links from external sources (e.g. click on link in skype)

Tags: firefox

This happens on both Fedora 20 and Ubuntu 14.04 with XFCE DE. When I click on any link (from external program), a new firefox window is opened with start page. That's all. I've already checked for launch command - "firefox %u". I have no idea what's the problem and what to do. Help, please.

I found out that only way - downgrade firefox. It lost his convenient menu, but problem is solved now. I'll be waiting hopefully for new version of firefox. Or, maybe, there is any other solution?

Comment: Downgrading your browser is a terrible idea. So many unfixed yet published security issues…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It also can be fixed just by typing "/usr/bin/firefox" instead of "firefox" in Preferred Applications

Comment: I've been looking for an answer for a while, yet it's so simple.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue was because in Preferred Applications it was set to "Ubuntu Tour" instead of "Firefox".

To change it, search in the Dash for "Preferred Applications" or "Details" and select "Default Applications" on the left.